# align iframes inline with other elements

Tags: html, css

iam trying to align several iframes in a parent div that all will be displayed inline with some margins.
This is how i want the finished solution to look like (created with buttons to show the expected results):

```css
    #content {
      border: solid 3px #00FF00;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #content h2 {
      margin-left: 15px;
    }

    #content button {
      margin-left: 15px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
     }
```

```html
    <div id="content">
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
      <button>Button 3</button>
      <button>Button 4</button>
      <button>Button 5</button>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sovap/9du1rz56/

And this is the struture i need to update:

```css
    #content {
      border: solid 3px #00FF00;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #content h2 {
      margin-left: 15px;
    }

    #content iframe, button {
      margin-left: 15px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="content">
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <iframe src="some.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      <button>Button 2</button>
      <iframe src="some.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      <button>Button 3</button>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sovap/zxm8wjso/

So what needs to be don with those iframes that they will be inline with buttons?

Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `display:flex` and `align-items:flex-end` to parent div.

```css
#content {
  border: solid 3px #00FF00;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
}

#content h2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#content iframe, button {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <iframe src="some.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <iframe src="some.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```